# How to loop through the number of rows from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation like this..

I want to loop through a table and get each row as a parameter to another procedure

It is like this ..

```
while ( select @myTitle=Title from tblBooks )
   select * from tblBorrowed where Title = @myTitle
```

It is just a pseudo code it is an error in sql..

How to do it in SQL Server to view a result like this

`tblBooks`:

```
ID     Title
------------
 1      A 
 2      B
 3      C
 4      D
```

`tblBorrowed`:

```
ID     Title
------------
 1      A 
 2      A
 3      A
 4      D
 5      C
 6      C
 7      D
```

And I want to make a result like this

```
Title   Borrowed
------------
 A      3
 B      0
 C      2
 D      2
```

Which is the 'Borrowed' column is the no of times Book being borrowed

How can I do that? Any idea? I appreciate it..

Thank you so much..

Comment: You could do this using a cursor. But you don't want to. What you want it learning how to do "group by"

Comment: How to do it? can you give me some idea

Comment: Read up on "group by" -- it is very basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not really a procedural language where you loop through rows to get your result. You *can* do that, but it's really slow.

Most things in SQL can be done without loops. It looks like all you need is a `group by`.

Start with something like this:

```
select 
   Title,                -- Title field for the group
   count(*) as Borrowed  -- "Borrowed" is the number of rows in the group
from tblBorrowed
group by Title           -- groups are determined by looking at Title field
```

This makes SQL Server split the results into groups based on Title, like this:

```
ID     Title
------------
 1      A 
 2      A
 3      A

 4      D
 7      D

 5      C
 6      C
```

Then for each of those groups, it counts the number of rows - `count(*)` and reports one row back for each group, with its row-count.

```
Title   Borrowed
------------
 A      3
 D      2
 C      2
```

Notice that you don't have `B` in there, because there are no rows to count. If you do need to have a row for `B`, then you'll have to use a `join`.

```
select
   book.Title,
   borrow.ID
from tblBooks book
left join tblBorrowed borrow on borrow.Title=book.Title
```

Now you are starting with the `tblBooks` table (including `B`) and trying to match each row to one or more `tblBorrowed` rows. If there's no `tblBorrowed` row, you still have the one `tblBooks` row.

You get something like this:

```
Title  ID
---------
A      1
A      2
A      3
B      null
C      5
C      6
D      4
D      7
```

So now you can group that query and count it again:

```
select
   book.Title,
   count(*)
from tblBooks book
left join tblBorrowed borrow on borrow.Title=book.Title
group by book.Title
```

And it gets split into groups:

```
Title  ID
---------
A      1
A      2
A      3

B      null

C      5
C      6

D      4
D      7
```

And each group is counted:

```
Title  ID
---------
A      3
B      0
C      2
D      2
```

Comment: This is not the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT      TB.Title, COUNT(BO.ID) AS Borrowed
FROM        tblBooks AS TB LEFT OUTER JOIN
            tblBorrowed AS BO ON BO.Title = TB.Title
GROUP BY    TB.Title
```

Use `tblBorrowed` column in **COUNT()** function

`COUNT(BO.ID)` returns **0**. `COUNT(*)` returns **1**